# Calculation for lowering temperature in a room… room-fridge with water mist?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, heat-transfer

I was looking at how the water cools my body when it evaporates off it. Then I thought the specific heat capacity could be used to calculate how much energy (i.e heat) would be taken out of a room when water that absorbed its heat is transferred out of the room.

I tried and researched all I could, but as I am not an physicist, I can't really get calculations together.

I have a setup with one mister, which is simply a device that atomizes water to small drops (I have no clue how small), and a large fan (it draws air) on the ceiling to "suck" up the vapour and transfer it to the open.

Room size = 2m x 2m x 3m

Mister sprays 1L of water per minute (16.67ml per second), as tiny drops.

I am getting confused, as some water would probably vaporise and some would remain water. I think that the small drops have a large surface area, so absorb energy fast, and thus turn into gas (steam?). I can't understand how to calculate the heat energy transfer from the room to the water and steam, how to use ratios. All this is getting messed up the more I think of it.

Can someone direct me what I must calculate, as I'm really dumbfounded as of now.

Comment: Thank you for improving your question with additional information as to what you understand, what your doubts are and what you've taken into consideration. After removing some unnecessary commentary, I have now reopened it for answers.

Comment: This is actually a fairly complicated question. It will depend on the relative humidity in the environment, and the airflow into and out of the room. The water droplets will evaporate until the temperature in the room reaches the dew point (which depends on temp and rh). But they will also increase the RH of the room,  thus increasing the dew point over time unless the moist air is vented.

Comment: @Drew If by "vented" you mean let out, then I clearly state that the ceiling exhaust fan will throw the air out of the room.

Comment: @ElFlea where does the make up air come from? What's the relative humidity and temperature of that air? What's the flow rate?